# Zooming difference between word document and pdf document

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat, zoom

I can easily zoom in on a document when I am using the Drawboard pdf application. Even in the Acrobat PDF application, zooming mechanism works smoothly(when I zoom in too much). But on the other hand, zooming in on word documents is a bit more difficult since zooming into images is a bit weird. It is not as smooth as the pdf format. So is there a way to make it happen or should I convert word documents into pdf every time I need to work easily?

Comment: You need to post example documents.

Comment: The method that Word uses to render to the screen is nothing like the method that PDF apps use to render to the screen.  PDF files have a predetermined size and elements.  Word docs do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF is *specifically designed* to be printed and look exactly the same whenever you use it. Displaying and printing on different devices with different resolutions involves "zooming" so to speak, so it is no surprise its zooming is correct and expected.

Word documents are not designed to look exactly the same everywhere. Word is a word and text processor, not a pre-print preparation software.

Answer (score 0):

In Word Options - Advanced - tick **Do not compress images in files**
[image]